# Message format in java and how to replicate the same in Golang

Tags: java, string, go, messageformat

Here's the Java code:

```
AtomicInteger obIndex = new AtomicInteger(0);
MessageFormat.format("{0,number,#},{1},{2},{3},\"{4}\"",
    obIndex.getAndIncrement(),
    "5bb2b35c67525f9e845648df370652b8",
    "Vm:vm-289",
    "1.1.1.1:113",
    "ABC-Testvm-1");
```

Output:

```
0,5bb2b35c67525f9e845648df370652b8,Vm:vm-289,1.1.1.1:113,"ABC-Testvm-1"
```

I tried this in Go:

```
value := fmt.Sprintf("%d,%s,%s,%s,%s",
    0,
    "5bb2b35c67525f9e845648df370652b8",
    "Vm:vm-289",
    "1.1.1.1:113", "ABC-Testvm-1")
fmt.Println(value)
```

Which outputs:

```
0,5bb2b35c67525f9e845648df370652b8,Vm:vm-289,1.1.1.1:113,ABC-Testvm-1
```

What is the significance of `{0,number,#}` and how can I get the same in Go?

Comment: I tried to format your code, but there are some significant errors in it so that I cannot guess what your are trying to do. Please format your code properly and try to formulate a precise question.

Comment: here is executed code in Java:
http://tpcg.io/7P5ih4

Comment: @mbuechmann one i tired in Go
https://play.golang.org/p/O_wUZjQ4Ux3

Comment: @mbuechmann i have copied the links , i am looking for the similar thing done in java in Golang

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is detailed at [`java.text.MessageFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html). The string you pass to [`MessageFormat.format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) is a *pattern*. A pattern consists of *format elements*. The form of a format element is:

```
 FormatElement:
         { ArgumentIndex }
         { ArgumentIndex , FormatType }
         { ArgumentIndex , FormatType , FormatStyle }
```

So in the first format element:

```
{0,number,#}
```

`0` is the argument index whose value to format.

`number` is a format type, and `#` is a format style, more specifically a *subformat pattern*. This means the argument will be formatted using a subformat of:

```
new DecimalFormat(subformatPattern, DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(getLocale()))
```

The `#` subformat is described at [`java.text.DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). It simply means to not use fraction digits, only display it as an integer, and if it is not an integer, it will be rounded (using the [`RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_EVEN) mode).

In Go to format an integer number, you may simply use the `%d` verb as you did, which will yield the same output format for integer numbers. If the number is a floating point number, this won't work (`%d` can only be used for integers). If the number is a floating point number, use the `%f` verb, more specifically `%.0f` to tell it to round to an integer, or the shortest form `%.f`.

Also your Java version puts the last argument in double quotes, so you should do the same in Go.

```
value := fmt.Sprintf("%d,%s,%s,%s,\"%s\"",
    0,
    "5bb2b35c67525f9e845648df370652b8",
    "Vm:vm-289",
    "1.1.1.1:113", "ABC-Testvm-1")

fmt.Println(value)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/o9Vatozde6_d)):

```
0,5bb2b35c67525f9e845648df370652b8,Vm:vm-289,1.1.1.1:113,"ABC-Testvm-1"
```